# language is being reset on boot

Tags: settings, 5.1-lollipop, boot, languages, dual-sim

I have recently purchased a new phone (Laude M8), which is the first Android 5.1 phone I have used, and also the first phone I have used which supports dual SIM cards.

I have only one SIM card inserted, which is from a Lithuanian carrier. When I restart my phone, it boots with the Lithuanian language selected and I have to manually change it back to English every time in Settings -> Language & Input. Disabling the SIM card in the options makes no difference to this behavior, but physically removing the SIM card works to stop it changing the language.

Is there a way to force it to always boot into the English language with this SIM card inserted?

My previous phone, a single-SIM model (LG L70) running Android 4.4 KitKat, did not have this problem with the same SIM card.

I haven't found any setting anywhere in the UI that would control this, including using the search feature inside the Settings menu.

EDIT: I have just discovered that coming out of aeroplane mode also changes the language to Lithuanian.

Comment: Same here with LG G4S... There's a thread about it in [androidcentral.com](http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-g3/480413-why-my-lg-g3-switching-german-language-daily.html)